# How to sort collection by created_at attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working with Ruby on Rails 2.3.8 and I've got a collection that is built from other two collections, as follows:

```
@coll1 = Model1.all
@coll2 = Model2.all

@coll = @coll1 << @coll2
```

Now, I would like to sort that collection by `created_at` attribute in descendant order. So, I did the following:

```
@sorted_coll = @coll.sort {|a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at}
```

And I've got the following exception:

```
undefined method `created_at' for #<Array:0x5c1d440>
```

eventhought it exists for those models.

Could anyboy help me please?

Comment: If you're sorting an array of objects you should use `sort_by` instead of `sort`. There are times `sort` is faster, but object access isn't one of them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You were pushing another array as another element into the `@coll1` array, you have two options:

Flatten the resulting array:

```
@coll.flatten!
```

Or preferably just use the `+` method:

```
@coll = @coll1 + @coll2
```

And for sorting you should use [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003120):

```
@sorted_coll = @coll.sort_by { |obj| obj.created_at }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@coll1 = Model1.all
@coll2 = Model2.all

@coll = @coll1 + @coll2

@sorted_coll = @coll.sort_by { |a| a.created_at }
```

Answer (score 2):

you have a nested array inside your @coll variable. like so: http://codepad.org/jQ9cgpM1

try

```
@sorted = @coll1 + @coll2
```

then sort.

Answer (score 0):

As Jed Schneider indicates, the solution is:

```
@coll1 = Model1.all
@coll2 = Model2.all

@coll = @coll1 + @coll2 # use + instead of <<
```